# Absolute Value in Smooth Infinitesimal Analysis

Tags: topos-theory, smooth-functions, infinitesimals, synthetic-differential-geometry

I am a bit confused about how [synthetic differential geometry](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/synthetic+differential+geometry) deals with certain compositions of smooth maps.

We have a square root function $f(x)=\sqrt{x}\colon \mathbb{R}^+\to \mathbb{R}^+$ and we have the squaring function $g(x)=x^2\colon \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^+$ as smooth functions. But the composition $f(g(x))=|x|$ is not smooth so it shouldn't exist in a setting of smooth worlds.

I think the issue is with the formation of $\mathbb{R}^+$.

I guess my main question is if there is this composition $f\circ g$ and if not, exactly why?

Comment: Is $f$ smooth?$\,$

Comment: In SDG the square root function is typically defined only on the *positive* reals, so that $0$ is not in its domain.

Comment: Already in ordinary differential geometry I would not regard $\sqrt{x}$ as being smooth on $\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$ at $0$ and I doubt the situation changes in SDG. If you remove $0$ then there is no problem.

Comment: $g$ would have to have domain $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{ 0 \}$ (or some subset) in order to have a codomain of $\mathbb{R}^+$.